# Need a Javascript calendar that should only show next dates corresponding to the date in textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi all i would like to show the pop-up calendar when i click on calendar in my application. Previously i will have a date in my text-box  that may be any date in the current year. What i need is if my date in text-box is some thing like 01/03/2008.. I would like to show only the next dates after that, and i would like to disable all the Previous dates as non-selectable.

The script i used is this

```
 function positionInfo(object) {

var p_elm = object;

this.getElementLeft = getElementLeft;
function getElementLeft() {
var x = 0;
var elm;
if(typeof(p_elm) == "object"){
  elm = p_elm;
} else {
  elm = document.getElementById(p_elm);
}
while (elm != null) {
  x+= elm.offsetLeft;
  elm = elm.offsetParent;
}
return parseInt(x);
}

this.getElementWidth = getElementWidth;
function getElementWidth(){
var elm;
if(typeof(p_elm) == "object"){
  elm = p_elm;
} else {
  elm = document.getElementById(p_elm);
}
 return parseInt(elm.offsetWidth);
}

  this.getElementRight = getElementRight;
  function getElementRight(){
  return getElementLeft(p_elm) + getElementWidth(p_elm);
    }

    this.getElementTop = getElementTop;
     function getElementTop() {
    var y = 0;
   var elm;
   if(typeof(p_elm) == "object"){
    elm = p_elm;
  } else {
    elm = document.getElementById(p_elm);
  }
  while (elm != null) {
  y+= elm.offsetTop;
  elm = elm.offsetParent;
}
return parseInt(y);
}

 this.getElementHeight = getElementHeight;
  function getElementHeight(){
  var elm;
  if(typeof(p_elm) == "object"){
   elm = p_elm;
  } else {
   elm = document.getElementById(p_elm);
  }
   return parseInt(elm.offsetHeight);
 }

 this.getElementBottom = getElementBottom;
 function getElementBottom(){
  return getElementTop(p_elm) + getElementHeight(p_elm);
}
 }

 function CalendarControl() {

 var calendarId = 'CalendarControl';
 var currentYear = 0;
  var currentMonth = 0;
  var currentDay = 0;

 var selectedYear = 0;
 var selectedMonth = 0;
  var selectedDay = 0;

 var months =     ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
 var dateField = null;

function getProperty(p_property){
var p_elm = calendarId;
var elm = null;

if(typeof(p_elm) == "object"){
  elm = p_elm;
} else {
  elm = document.getElementById(p_elm);
}
if (elm != null){
  if(elm.style){
    elm = elm.style;
    if(elm[p_property]){
      return elm[p_property];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
}

 function setElementProperty(p_property, p_value, p_elmId){
var p_elm = p_elmId;
var elm = null;

if(typeof(p_elm) == "object"){
  elm = p_elm;
} else {
  elm = document.getElementById(p_elm);
}
if((elm != null) && (elm.style != null)){
  elm = elm.style;
  elm[ p_property ] = p_value;
}
}

 function setProperty(p_property, p_value) {
setElementProperty(p_property, p_value, calendarId);
 }

  function getDaysInMonth(year, month) {
return [31,((!(year % 4 ) && ( (year % 100 ) || !( year % 400 ) ))?29:28),31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][month-1];
}

 function getDayOfWeek(year, month, day) {
var date = new Date(year,month-1,day)
return date.getDay();
}

this.setDate = setDate;
 function setDate(year, month, day) {
  if (dateField) {
  if (month < 10) {month = "0" + month;}
  if (day < 10) {day = "0" + day;}

  var dateString = month+"-"+day+"-"+year;
  dateField.value = dateString;
  hide();
  }
return;
 }

  this.changeMonth = changeMonth;
 function changeMonth(change) {
  currentMonth += change;
  currentDay = 0;
if(currentMonth > 12) {
  currentMonth = 1;
  currentYear++;
  } else if(currentMonth < 1) {
  currentMonth = 12;
  currentYear--;
  }

calendar = document.getElementById(calendarId);
calendar.innerHTML = calendarDrawTable();
}

this.changeYear = changeYear;
function changeYear(change) {
currentYear += change;
currentDay = 0;
calendar = document.getElementById(calendarId);
calendar.innerHTML = calendarDrawTable();
}

function getCurrentYear() {
var year = new Date().getYear();
if(year < 1900) year += 1900;
return year;
}

function getCurrentMonth() {
return new Date().getMonth() + 1;
} 

function getCurrentDay() {
return new Date().getDate();
 }

 function calendarDrawTable() {

  var dayOfMonth = 1;
  var validDay = 0;
  var startDayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(currentYear, currentMonth, dayOfMonth);
  var daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);
  var css_class = null; //CSS class for each day

  var table = "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>";
  table = table + "<tr class='header'>";
    table = table + "  <td colspan='2' class='previous'><a  href='javascript:changeCalendarControlMonth(-1);'>&lt;</a> <a href='javascript:changeCalendarControlYear(-1);'>&laquo;</a></td>";
table = table + "  <td colspan='3' class='title'>" + months[currentMonth-1] + "<br>" + currentYear + "</td>";
table = table + "  <td colspan='2' class='next'><a href='javascript:changeCalendarControlYear(1);'>&raquo;</a> <a href='javascript:changeCalendarControlMonth(1);'>&gt;</a></td>";
table = table + "</tr>";
table = table + "<tr><th>S</th><th>M</th><th>T</th><th>W</th><th>T</th><th>F</th><th>S</th></tr>";

for(var week=0; week < 6; week++) {
  table = table + "<tr>";
  for(var dayOfWeek=0; dayOfWeek < 7; dayOfWeek++) {
    if(week == 0 && startDayOfWeek == dayOfWeek) {
      validDay = 1;
    } else if (validDay == 1 && dayOfMonth > daysInMonth) {
      validDay = 0;
    }

    if(validDay) {
      if (dayOfMonth == selectedDay && currentYear == selectedYear && currentMonth == selectedMonth) {
        css_class = 'current';
      } else if (dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6) {
        css_class = 'weekend';
      } else {
        css_class = 'weekday';
      }

      table = table + "<td><a class='"+css_class+"' href=\"javascript:setCalendarControlDate("+currentYear+","+currentMonth+","+dayOfMonth+")\">"+dayOfMonth+"</a></td>";
      dayOfMonth++;
    } else {
      table = table + "<td class='empty'>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
  }
  table = table + "</tr>";
}

table = table + "<tr class='header'><th colspan='7' style='padding: 3px;'><a href='javascript:hideCalendarControl();'>Close</a></td></tr>";
table = table + "</table>";

return table;
}

 this.show = show;
 function show(field) {

// If the calendar is visible and associated with
// this field do not do anything.
if (dateField == field) {
  return;
} else {
  dateField = field;
}

if(dateField) {
  try {
    var dateString = new String(dateField.value);
    var dateParts = dateString.split("-");

    selectedMonth = parseInt(dateParts[0],10);
    selectedDay = parseInt(dateParts[1],10);
    selectedYear = parseInt(dateParts[2],10);
  } catch(e) {}
}

if (!(selectedYear && selectedMonth && selectedDay)) {
  selectedMonth = getCurrentMonth();
  selectedDay = getCurrentDay();
  selectedYear = getCurrentYear();
}

currentMonth = selectedMonth;
currentDay = selectedDay;
currentYear = selectedYear;

if(document.getElementById){

  calendar = document.getElementById(calendarId);
  calendar.innerHTML = calendarDrawTable(currentYear, currentMonth);

  setElementProperty('display', 'block', 'CalendarControlIFrame');
  setProperty('display', 'block');

  var fieldPos = new positionInfo(dateField);
  var calendarPos = new positionInfo(calendarId);

  var x = fieldPos.getElementLeft();
  var y = fieldPos.getElementBottom();
  x=x+155;
  y=y-22;
  setProperty('left', x + "px");
  setProperty('top', y + "px");
  setElementProperty('left', x + "px", 'CalendarControlIFrame');
  setElementProperty('top', y + "px", 'CalendarControlIFrame');
  setElementProperty('width', calendarPos.getElementWidth() + "px", 'CalendarControlIFrame');
  setElementProperty('height', calendarPos.getElementHeight() + "px", 'CalendarControlIFrame');
}
}

 this.hide = hide;
   function hide() {
    if(dateField) {
     setProperty('display', 'none');
    setElementProperty('display', 'none', 'CalendarControlIFrame');
    dateField = null;
   }
  }
 }

   var calendarControl = new CalendarControl();

function showCalendarControl(textField) {
 calendarControl.show(textField);

 }

  function hideCalendarControl() {
  calendarControl.hide();
  }

    function setCalendarControlDate(year, month, day) {
    calendarControl.setDate(year, month, day);
   }

  function changeCalendarControlYear(change) {
calendarControl.changeYear(change);
 }

function changeCalendarControlMonth(change) {
calendarControl.changeMonth(change);
}

document.write("<iframe id='CalendarControlIFrame' src='javascript:false;'      frameBorder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>");
document.write("<div id='CalendarControl'></div>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working. Test it well though.

The formatting is not working for some reason.

So, I pasted it onto shorttext.com. Here's the link : 
[link text](http://shorttext.com/d1d47o7e0m)

Comment: Did it work's well enough to the one i asked means i would like to disable all the previous date fields of the calendar according to the date that was in text box

Comment: declared three variables : minDay,minMonth and minYear and some changes in drawCalendarTable method. Use a file diff software to check changes

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel... Take a look at [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com).